# How can I run AWS Glue Crawler every 6 hours daily?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-glue

I want to run AWS Glue Crawler every 6 hours automatically daily.

Can I use Cron Expression available on Crawler as below :

```
Minutes Hours   Day of month    Month   Day of week Year
*       0/6     *               *        ?           *
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the expression in CloudWatch rules. The correct one is:

```
0 /6 ? * * *
```

[image]